# Animate Scale of FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, animation, android-framelayout

I created a new FrameLayout and set it to the following start parameters:

```
        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0);
                layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    main_layout.addView(layout);
```

After that I want to animate it (scale) from (0|0) to (400|600)

```
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0, 400, 0, 600, 200, 300);
        anim.setDuration(400);
        anim.setAnimationListener(this);
        layout.setAnimation(anim);
```

Unfortunatelly, the width and height of the FrameLayout keeps unaffected. The AnimationListener tells me that the Animation finishes, but nothing changed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try this one
ActivityOptions anim = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0,0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());